# Request data once on a service shared between two components

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-httpclient

I have two components that inject the same service. One component needs to function independently of the other component, but may be be added to the other component at any time, and both components need the same data. I want to avoid the data being loaded twice (i.e, just load it once regardless of which component requested the data).

The shared service:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserDetailsService {
    private userDetailsSubject: BehaviorSubject<UserDetails> = new BehaviorSubject<UserDetails>(new UserDetails());
    public currentModel: Observable<UserDetails> = this.userDetailsSubject.asObservable();

    constructor(private userDetailsRepository: UserDetailsRepository) {}

    public loadUserDetails(id: string) {
        // loadUserDetails makes a HttpClient get call which returns the result as an Observable
        this.userDetailsRepository.loadUserDetails(id)
            .subscribe(details => this.userDetailsSubject.next(details));
    }
}
```

The first component:

```
export class UserLookupComponent implements OnInit {

    // Other logic ...

    // The user is loaded via lookup.
    public user: User;

    constructor(private detailsService: UserDetailsService) {}

    public loadUserDetails() {
        this.detailsService.loadUserDetails(user.id);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.detailsService.currentModel.subscribe(details => {
            this.user.details = details;
        });
    }

    // Other logic...
}
```

The second component is virtually identical to the first component, with different other logic relevant to its purpose. It's basically an Overview component which should get the details for the user if they're not already loaded using `this.detailsService.loadUserDetails(user.id)`, and setting the user's details using `this.detailsService.currentModel.subscribe...` exactly the same way the first component does.

The issue however is that the data is being requested twice, and I want to avoid this behavior and only load the data once. I have tried setting the subject to a `Subject<string>`, and adding a `debounceTime` and `mergeMap(id => this.userDetailsRepository.loadUserDetails(id))` to the currentModel, but the same thing happens. How can I only retrieve the details once?

I should also note that the User is being retrieved and set using another Service. This service is also shared between both components (so they can both get the same user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited based on below comments

If you can initialize userDetailsSubject as null...

In Component 1, call loadUserDetails in ngOnInit after your subscription to currentModel.
Service...

```
public loadUserDetails(id: string) {
    this.userDetailsSubject.next(new UserDetails())
    this.userDetailsRepository.loadUserDetails(id)
        .subscribe(details => this.userDetailsSubject.next(details));
}
```

Component 2... in ngOnInit...

```
this.detailsService.currentModel.subscribe(details => {
        if (!details) this.loadUserDetails();
        else this.user.details = details;
    });
```

Comment: This will only load the data once and never again. If I perform a lookup for a new user, it should get the details for that new user once, which is shared with other components, but it doesn't do that with your solution.

Comment: @driima, so what is your condition for firing a new request?

Comment: Component 1 (the lookup component) requests user details when a user is loaded. Component 2 (the overview for the user) should only request user details if they are not loaded. Both components have access to the user via a shared service, but Component 2 can be used independently of Component 1 (i.e. it can load a user itself... Component 2 might be used in another page without the need for Component 1 and should be able to load the user details in case of such an event).

Comment: @driima, so you want component 1 to ALWAYS load, but component 2 to load only if there is no data? or should component 2 load only if component 1 isn't active?

Comment: @TzannetosPhilippakos the first one - 1 ALWAYS loads the data, 2 ONLY loads if there's no data.

Comment: @driima Sorry failed to take into account the time component 1 is still loading.... new edit above.